# Gimp: quick way to cycle through pencil/brush presets?

Tags: gimp, brush

I have created 6 different pencil pre-sets with different diameters. What I want is to be able to cycle up and down from one pre-set to the next, preferably with a keyboard shortcut. How do I set this up?

I tried using "increase brush size more" but that only increases by 10, and on larger diameters I want more than 10 pixels.

ETA: IS it possible to do this in other software? I'm not particularly attached to GIMP, it's just what I've got...

Answer (score 2):

I think there is currently no shortcut-able actions for switching the tool presets.

Regarding the brush size: there is a fast way to double and half the size with shortcuts, all you have to do is to assign them to the tools-value-2-increase/decrease-percent actions. I've used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> in the following example (the rest are the default values):

[image: GIMP keyboard shortcuts: tools-value-2-*]

Answer (score 0):

In the time that I've used GIMP, I haven't ever found a keyboard shortcut that helped me scroll through my brushes faster, nor did I find a shortcut that helped me increase the brush size...

Nonetheless, I think Photoshop (no matter the version, I believe) should have this feature. I've seen people go through the brushes insanely fast, and I've also noticed that they resized the brush without going into the brush menu. You can set the keyboard shortcut you want once you go into Photoshop, too.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle between brushes in a set on the keyboard using the app MyPaint. You would have to create a set of brushes, and stick them together into a brush group. Then, you can call up each brush using the keyboard by pressing a number on the keyboard corresponding to the brush you want. So you would press '1' for the first brush, '2' for the second, so on and so forth.

MyPaint in general is an app that has clearly had a lot of thought put into it regarding keyboard shortcuts; I use it with a Wacom enabled laptop in and bring it to open studio sketching sessions in full-screen mode, and it is very easy to call up dialogs as needed and dismiss them via the keyboard as well as modify parameters of the tools you're working with without visiting dialogs.